# How to number households?

Tags: stata

I have a set of household data with more than 20,000 records of 4200 households. In my data set there is no any column for household ID & all the records are per household member. There is a column for person's serial no & with each & every "1", the household should be changed.( i.e: if we start to number households, with the very 1st person's serial no when it's equal to 1, the corresponding HH_ID should be "1". Once the next record when person's serial no=1 meets, then the HH_ID should be 2.) So I want to add a column named HH_ID & number it from 1-4200. How could I write a program using STATA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is (assuming a variable `personid` for person identifier)

```
 . gen hhid = sum(personid == 1)
```

That's it. The explanation is longer than the code. The expression `personid == 1` evaluates as 1 when true and 0 when false. For the first household, first person, this will be 1, and for the other persons in the same household 0. For the second household, first person, this will be 1, and so on. The function `sum()` gives the cumulative or running sum, so that you should end with something that goes 1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,... Clearly the actual numbers of 1s, 2s, 3s etc. will depend on the numbers of persons in the households.

On true and false in Stata see

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/index.html

Comment: I would specify that as `gen long hhid = ...`, but that is probably a matter of taste. (I don't trust Stata's defaults on variable types, let's put it that way.)

Comment: That's excellent advice for big datasets. A `float` will be fine for the problem indicated.

Comment: I used "gen hhid = sum(personid == 1)" & it worked. Hope it won't be wrong even without long or float. Anyway I'll keep in mind to use long when handling big data sets. Thanks a million for the great replies.